# when add to cart then page is very slow after cache is page speed up in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I have recently upgraded the Magento from 1.6.2 to 1.9.2 and I found the cart page is too slow. Not only when I add the product to cart, but also when I just load the cart page. I did confirm that the site is using the default cart controller. Here is the profiler report

Answer (score 0):

You can use the browser inspector to check which js, images and so on needs time to load.

The time problem could be also a server delay.

Search Google for Magento speed optimization.

Deactivate logging, enable cache, enable compiler to get faster results. f.e.

Hope this helps.

Comment: already enable cache and compile no other issue but only issue when add to cart page once clear the cache after speed up but after 15 20 min same issue repeat.

Comment: Like I wrote: "You can use the browser inspector to check which js, images and so on needs time to load."